# Anchor Link - Open accordion on other site

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a site with an accordion. Now when i click on my start-site on a link which is a link to another site with an anchor i want to open this specific accordion. I explain the work-flow:

1. I click on a link on my home-site. `/news/#example1`
2. The news site opens and its scrolling to the example1 id which is closed.
3. The accordion entry with id example1 should open.

Comment: can you show us the code you have tried?

Answer (score 1):

As Mathias said, you have to take the hash from the url. But if you already have an accordion jquery plugin set to the element with the id "example1", you have to trigger the element if the hash for this is on the url.

Example:

If the html is:

`<div id="example1">
    <div class="accordion-header">Some title here for the content</div>
    <div class="accordion-content">The actual content of the accordion</div>
</div>`

Then you have to do this:

```
var hash = window.location.hash; 
if(hash == "#example1")
$('#example1').find('.accordion-header').trigger('click');
```

And if every news content has its own id, you could do this:

```
var hash = window.location.hash; 
$(hash).find('.accordion-header').trigger('click');
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You can get the hash from the URL, using the code below.
2. Write a script that opens the accordion (`li`?)

> var hash = window.location.hash;
>               $('#'+hash).show();